# Scrapy capitalizes request headers

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm setting the headers following way

```
headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
...
}
```

And calling request like that:

```
yield scrapy.Request(url='https:/myurl.com/', callback=self.parse, 
headers=headers, cookies=cookies, meta={'proxy': 'http://localhost:8888'})
```

And it makes that scrapy capitalizes all these headers and it looks like that (I'm using Charles proxy for debugging):

```
Accept: 
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

And this is not working correctly for my case.

If I'm using curl and set headers lowercase

```
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
cache-control: no-cache
```

everything works like a charm.

Is there any way how I can disable this capitalizing behavior in Scrapy?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem?  HTTP headers should be case insensitive.

Comment: You can answer the above question by using `curl` with capitalized headers and checking whether it gives the same output. If it does, your problem isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Yea, I'm pretty sure about it. I guess the website I'm trying to parse is handling it some special way.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done out of the box with Scrapy.

Reason: it is managing headers in a case insensitive way by design (see: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/http/headers.py). Guess they do it to avoid trouble with duplicate headers.

So most probably you'll have to do a fork and roll your own implementation of header handling or do at least some monkey patching.

But I'm wondering whether that is really what you need. I know that some websites do request header fingerprinting to detect bots, but the capitalized headers generated by scrapy look much more non-bot than the all-lowercase headers you want to generate for your requests.

Answer (score 1):

This is my workaround. In your spider file you first create a class derived from Headers.

```
from copy import deepcopy
from scrapy.http import Headers
class Headers2(Headers):

    def __init__(self, seq=None, encoding='utf-8'):

        Headers.__init__(self, seq, encoding)

    def normkey(self, key):
        """Method to normalize dictionary key access"""
        return key.lower()
```

Then in your spider code

```
req = scrapy.Request(
                url=url,
                headers=header,
                callback=self.get_parcel_url
            )

h = Header2(copy.deepcopy(req.headers))
req.headers = h
```

Answer (score -1):

I've had blocking issues with two sites due to this. Here is my workaround that has worked both times:

```
headers={
    "":"accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
    "":"accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7",
}
```